# How to define a REST endpoint in fastAPI for <input type="file"> (and make it work with angular)?

Tags: angular, file-upload, fastapi

I'm doing this [angular tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-file-upload/). I'm trying to create a backend endpoint using python fastAPI that receives the data via HttpClient POST, but I'm struggling to do so.
(angular 13.0.2, python 3.7, fastapi 0.70.0)

**html template code:**

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileUpload> 

<div class="file-upload">

    {{fileName || "No file uploaded yet."}}

    <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

**corresponding component ts code:**

```
  onFileSelected(event) {

    const file: File = event.target.files[0]
    console.log(`onFileSelected(${file.name})`)

    if (file) {
      this.fileName = file.name;
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("thumbnail", file);
      const upload$ = this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/thumbnail-upload", formData);
      upload$.subscribe();
      console.log("upload done?")
  }
```

**fastapi code:** inpired by [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/)

```
@app.post("/thumbnail-upload")
def create_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(file)
    return {"file_size": len(file)}
```

There seems to be some OK communication going on, but I'm stuck here:

**output from uvicorn server:**

```
←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:18231 - "←[1mPOST /thumbnail-upload   HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m422 Unprocessable Entity←[0m
```

**output in browser debug console:**

```
zone.js:2863 POST http://localhost:8000/thumbnail-upload 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
core.mjs:6495 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 422, statusText: 'Unprocessable Entity', url: 'http://localhost:8000/thumbnail-upload', ok: false, …}
```

How do I need to implement the fastAPI endpoint to get this running?
Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to angular/fastapi, if I forgot to include necessary information, pls. tell me what's missing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of the 422 error message will give you exactly what field is missing. From your code it seems to indicate that you're submitting the file under the `thumbnail` name, but you're using the `file` name in your FastAPI route. Since those two doesn't match, FastAPI doesn't find the file you're assuming is present. Either rename the form parameter to `file` or rename the FastAPI argument to `thumbnail`:

```
@app.post("/thumbnail-upload")
def create_file(thumbnail: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print(thumbnail)
    return {"file_size": len(thumbnail.file.read())}
```

The `UploadFile` object also exposes `file` to interact with the spooled file behind the scenes. Since it doesn't give you the bytes directly, I don't think calling `len` on it will do what you expected it to do.

Comment: Ok, this does the trick. Toying around, I found that `formData.append("file", file, file.name);` also works with my first implementation (yes, and `len(file)` threw an error). Can you shed some light on the importance of the parameter name in fastAPI? is it because formdata comes in key/value and is then treated as a kwarg?

Comment: A form can include multiple files, either under the same or different names. The parameter names need to match up for FastAPI to known which file the data is relevant for, and to know that it is _actually_ the expected parameter and not something random. It's probably clearer if you had used query args; `user_id=38` suddenly matching against `hits: int` would give you all kind of weird results.